# Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have this function in an unmanaged library and I want to call it in C#:

`unsigned char __stdcall InitDev(unsigned char comport, long BaudRate)`

and this is in C#

```
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport("*.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,CharSet =CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern byte[] InitDev(byte[] comport, [Out]long BaudRate);
```

but when I call this function in C# I get the following error

> "Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination."

```
string COM = "COM3";
byte[] ptr = new byte[1];
try
{
    ptr = InitDev(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(COM), 9600);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I am new to this if a little guidance is provided I will be able to resolve this issue

[image]

Comment: This function is next to impossible to call reliably in a C program, that gets never better when you do it from C#.  You don't know how many elements are in the array and you don't know how to release it.  You'll have to talk to the programmer of this code to find out what that pointer means.  As long as you do, get him to fix it.  The baudrate argument is an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your native call is something like `unsigned char* InitDef(unsigned char*, long long &baudRate)` then you probably want to use `IntPtr` in the place of your `unsigned char*`. But first since it's managed/unmanaged mixing you should allocate that `byte[]` buffer for input and output :

```
byte[] pInBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("COM3");
// allocate unmanaged memory
IntPtr inputBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(pInBuffer.Length * sizeof(byte));
Marshal.Copy(pInBuffer, 0, inputBuffer, pInBuffer.Length);

// now your inputBuffer contains a native pointer to the `unsigned char*`
// and since your function returns a new pointer to some `unsigned char*`
// just retrieve it to IntPtr
IntPtr result = InitDev(inputBuffer, 9600);

// free your allocated memory
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(inputBuffer);
```

At this stage your `result` contains the value returned from `InitDev`.

---

*new definition of `InitDev` function*

```
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport("*.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,CharSet =CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr InitDev(IntPtr comport, [Out] long BaudRate);
```

All of the necessary calls, you can find on this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

***EDIT :***
Since your native call looks like this :`extern unsigned char __stdcall InitDev(unsigned char comport,long BaudRate);`
I'm guessing that the first parameter is just the last digit ( index ) of your `"COMn"` because `unsigned char`'s lowest possible value is 0 and COM's lowest index can be 0.

Try using this snippet :

```
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport("*.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,CharSet =CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern byte InitDev(byte comport, long BaudRate);
```

And then call it like so :

```
byte comIdx = 3;
byte result = InitDev(comIdx, 9600);
// byte should yield correct result now
```

Comment: Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsFormsApplication1!WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1::InitDev' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: Can you post exactly how the definition of `InitDev` looks in native .h file?

Comment: I have got the SDK of this device and it has this header file but nothing is explained in a proper manner... let me show it to you

Comment: extern unsigned char __stdcall InitDev(unsigned char comport,long  BaudRate);

Comment: C#'s equivalent of `unsigned char` is `byte` so instead of making `byte[]` or `IntPtr` you just have to use `byte`. I'll edit it up in a sec.

Comment: but since COM3 will make 4 bytes and the argument is unsigned char not a byte[] array equivalent so how to pass it 4 bytes...

Comment: @ShakoorAlam Look at the edit and let me know if it helped :)

Comment: Brother still the same Exception of PInvoke

Comment: I am attaching an image what document says

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150010/discussion-between-shakoor-alam-and-m-rogalski).

Comment: i changed the datatype Long to Int it ran without any error with your code.... and I am getting return 255